# How can I add a button to approve tasks to a sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to make the approval process easier. For this I have thought of adding a button to a column of a sharepoint list.

The user would see the list of tasks pending approval and clicking on the task button would automatically be approved.

How can i do this (workflow,javascript...)? Is that possible?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sharepoint workflow system, the user can approve from the task detail form already.

If you want to make it more user friendly as you suggested, you may program an extra field, using JSLink technology to customize the task list rendering or to add this approval button from an other list (I assume you are using sharepoint 2013 on premise) from which you call javascript API to trigger the approval.

Read more :

[JSOM Api to approve a task](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119323/approve-listitem-task-from-button-with-javascript)

[JSLINK](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37684.sharepoint-2013-jslink-client-side-rendering.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a workflow would work. I would have a separate "Approved" column that defaults to "No" (don't show it on the form). And run a workflow (upon form submit?) that changes the value of Approved to "Yes".